# How do I iterate through variables by name?

Tags: vb.net, variables

If I have the following code:

```
Private answer1 as boolean = false
Private answer2 as boolean = false
Private answer3 as boolean = false
.
.
Private answer100 as boolean = false

Private Sub check_answers()

     For x As Integer = 0 To 100
       if answer[x] = true then
          ' do something
       else
          ' do something else
       endif

     Next

End Sub
```

How do I iterate through all of the answer variables by name? the answer[x] option isn't working.
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use a dictionary instead of hundreds of fields?

Comment: `answer(N)` would work if it was an array of answers; A `List(of Boolean)` would be even better than an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

Correcting your code, it would be:

```
Private answers(100) as boolean
'The array starts from 0

Private Sub check_answers()
   For x As Integer = 0 To 100
      if answers(x) then 
         ' do something
      else
         ' do something else
      endif
   Next
End Sub
```

The array starts from 0 and the last element is the value used in declaration (for example, `answers(100)` would have 101 elements - from 0 to 100).

Comment: To get 101 elements in array in VB, you would `Dim a(100) as Boolean`. The value in the declaration is the last index of the array, not the number of elements in the array (which it would be in C#).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having 100 variables. Just have a single list.

```
Private answers As New List(Of Boolean)
```

Then you can check a single item in a list (not the '()' instead of '[]')

```
if answers(x) = true then
```

Also, you could pre-populate 100 items

```
For x As Integer = 1 To 100
    answers.Add(False)
Next
```

Comment: This works also, but it seems I can only give credit to one person.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create an array of the values that you want to iterate across:

```
Dim answer = {answer1, answer2, ...(and so on)} '***
```

You could take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e.aspx for more information on how to use arrays in VB.Net.

Beyond this, it is possible to do what you want using a technique called reflection - however I suspect that this might be more complicated than you wish. You can get a good introduction to using reflection in VB.net by reading this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163750.aspx .